# What is a bosom in a robe or a shirt?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

[image]

> This lady is wearing a white wedding dress with a pleated bosom.

I thought that bosom is the top part of a clothe, but I am not sure, and I am not sure if the phrase is correctly describing the picture.

Comment: You thought correctly. The word is being used to describe the upper part of the wedding dress, for reasons that are apparent. One of the definitions of bosom is..the part of a garment that covers the chest or the breast.               https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bosom

Comment: I agree you thought correctly. I think "bosom" is much more likely to be used to describe a part of a dress than a robe or shirt, because in a dress there is often a particular design for that part of the garment; while a robe or shirt might have such a design, they much more often just have cloth over that part of the body with nothing special about it.